# MySQL - Display key where a field occurs the same twice or more

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble putting together a MySql statement.
I have a table two fields. One is called "key" (primary key) and the other is called "number". "number" may occur as the same value more than once and I need to return a list of "number" that occurs more than once in the table.

...I tried this:

```
SELECT number FROM table HAVING COUNT(number) > 1;
```

Comment: You just need to add `group by number`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the group by section

```
SELECT number FROM table GROUP BY number HAVING COUNT(number) > 1;
```